# How do I query dynamically(?) in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure the title makes sense, so let me elaborate more. 
So in my Django project, each user has his own list with random integers like this : `numList = [1, 3, 4, 8, 10]`

And I have a model names Question, which looks like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default="")
    # And so on
```

Now I want to query Question objects that match the numbers in the list in my views.py.

```
def getQuestions(request):
    numList = [2, 3, 4, 1, 8] # this list contains random integers every time the function is called.
    
    questionsList = []
    for i in range(0, len(numList)):
        eachQuestion = Question.objects.filter(question_number=numList[i])
        questionsList.append(eachQuestion.values())
        i = i + 1

    # And so on
```

This is as far as I got. And this actually is inappropriate, because what I want is queryset, not list. How do I get queryset of questions that match the numbers in `numList`?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup to filter the `question_number`s occur in `numList`

```
def getQuestions(request):
    numList = [2, 3, 4, 1, 8]
    
    return Question.objects.filter(question_number__in=numList)
```

Answer (score 2):

in your case you can use `Question.objects.filter(question_number__in=numList)`

you can read about `__in` filter - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in